# Azure function displaying output on Webpage

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-functions

I want to run a PowerShell command from Azure function and the output should be displayed on a webpage. Can I achieve this from Azure functions? I know I can call PowerShell command from Azure function and I can also display a web page by calling Azure function. But can I combine both the worlds?

Here's the example to display a webpage from azure functions

https://anthonychu.ca/post/azure-functions-serve-html/

Comment: Put your effort first.

Comment: Sure you can. There are multiple ways to achieve this. What are you struggling with at the moment? You can just load up/create some HTML in your Function and return in to the caller, like your example does. The sample is using C#, but rewriting to PowerShell is feasible.